# Detecting bipartite graph

Tags: graph-algorithm, bipartite

I am just creating an algorithm to detect bipartite graphs, but I thought of some graph which I am not sure counts as bipartite, though my algorithm is saying it is.

The graph goes like

```
(A)--(B)

(C)
```

So this has 3 nodes but there is 1 edge between only `A` and `B`.
Is this actually bipartite?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can divide the nodes into two sets, such that all edges go between the two sets. F'rinstance, {A} and {B,C}.

Comment: So a node from one set doesn't actually have to connect to the the other set?

Comment: Correct. (And a comment can't be only eight characters.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your sample graph really is bipartite.

See, for example, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) which states in the introductory sentence...

> In the mathematical field of graph theory, a bipartite graph (or
>   bigraph) is a graph whose vertices can be divided into two disjoint
>   sets U and V such that every edge connects a vertex in U to one in V;
>   that is, U and V are each independent sets. Equivalently, a bipartite
>   graph is a graph that does not contain any odd-length cycles.

There are two ways you could divide this graph ("{A,C}, {B}" or "{B,C}, {A}") which would meet the conditions required for a bipartite graph.

There is no requirement for a bipartite graph to be a connected graph.